# How to upload password protected xlsx file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I tried to upload password protected xlsx with validation but i can't upload.. it throws filetype validation error.

```
$this->validate($request, [
'evidences' => 'required|max:10240|mimes:xls,xlsx'
]);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Where is this happening? Is this your code?

Comment: @MostafaBahri i have added a code above. you can check. the password protected xlsx file is not accepted as xls or xlsx file.

Comment: did you try using `mimetypes:application/vnd.ms-excel` instead?

Comment: but it seems that it is the uploader who have got problem with the file not the Laravel validation

Comment: Are you using windows? Mimes are not a good validation because it depends a bit on your OS. Windows for example, sometimes doesn't add mimetypes to the files because a key is not present in the registry. (mime is "" instead of what you expect).

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed yeah i aslo tried `mimetypes:application/vnd.ms-excel` and its a laravel validation error.

Comment: @IGP no i'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Where is the error being generated from @AnandMainali